# Strip is not allowing call to their API from our server instead it throw an exception

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Hi  we have integrated stripe api on our web application, It was working fine from last 2 years till today. Nothing has been changed on server configuration or Strip Library suddenly it has stopped working and throw an exception.

**Sequence of Calls:**

```
// Stripe Library Path, Installed through Composer
require_once( PAYMENT_DIR . '/stripe/init.php' );
//$stripe_secret_key = "stripe-secret-id-is-placed-here";
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey( $stripe_secret_key );

try {
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                "source" => $stripeToken,// This token is created from client end
                "email" => $user_email
            )
        );
        $stripeId = $customer->id;


    // charge customer by customer ID //
    $charge_amount = $stripe_payable_amount * 100;// dynamic amount user wants to oay
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        'amount' => $charge_amount,
        'currency' => $CurrentCurrency,//USD currency
        'customer' => $stripeId

    ));

} catch ( Exception $e ) {

    $response = $e->getMessage();

}
```

**Below is Exception:**

> Could not connect to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_CzC5Ji5XMVoI5z). Please check your internet connection and try again. If this problem persists, you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or let us know at support@stripe.com. (Network error [errno 7]: Failed connect to api.stripe.com:443; Operation now in progress).

We contacted stripe live chat support they said it is our server side issue, and opened a ticket through email to further investigate it.
**Stripe Response:**

> Sorry about the trouble you're having! This kind of error usually suggests that something isn't configured correctly on your server, eg. a DNS misconfiguration preventing you from reaching our servers. We'd recommend reaching out to your hosting provider to help you troubleshoot.

We have added [Stripe IP Address](https://stripe.com/docs/ips) in our Ip tables.
We made customers call through Postman it worked fine as shown in below Image.
[image]

Our server Ip is not mentioned or email address is not added in block list under radar on stripe dashboard. Stripe support will take 24-48 hours to further dig down this particular issue. If some body has any clue to get it fixed soon please help.

Comment: Stripe has a reachability test, if you try to run it on your server (not dev machine) do the requests go through or does it error? Unfortunately that curl error is super generic, so it could be anything. I'd also maybe chat with your host / server infra provider https://github.com/stripe/stripe-reachability

Comment: @duck we will try stripe reachability test, and further investigate the issue.

Comment: @duck I run script on our server, os  check and route check were successful. But ip check and curl_https failed. You can check each response on [image link](https://ibb.co/Jz5vf0d)

Answer (score 0):

Our application is hosted on AWS, actually block **port 443**, which is being used to call Stripe APIs from our server.

We reached their support and they unblock mentioned port no, finally stripe payment gateways is working again.

**Note:** Avoid sending lot of traffic while automation tests scripts for payment flow.

Comment: I'd just note that AWS doesn't block 443, but they do provide the tools for *you* to do so.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes you are we can define rules in security group at AWS console, In our case,it block our server to send request on Stripe API which were using port 443 at (api.stripe.com:443). We have to contact their support to get it working again.